# Discord.js | I'm trying to check if a role has a specific permission for a mute role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Basically I'm making a ultra customizable discord bot, and you have to specify in the config file the name of the role you want to use when you mute someone. And as a fail-safe in case the role is invalid or misspelled the bot looks himself for a role that has the permission "SEND_MESSAGE" turned off.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the guild's [RoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager) for a role that does not have the permission by using `.find()`. This will return the first role that does not have `'SEND_MESSAGES'`

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache
   .find(r => !r.permissions.has('SEND_MESSAGES'));
```

`role` will return `undefined` if a role without `'SEND_PERMISSIONS'` was not found.

If you want to increase accuracy of finding a muted role given that the name is misspelled check what the name of the role starts with.

```js
// Account for spelling mistakes, given that "mu" in "muted" is correct
const role = message.guild.roles.cache
   .find(r => !r.permissions.has('SEND_MESSAGES') && r.name.toLowerCase().startsWith('mu'));
```

Comment: From the OP's question: "you have to specify in the config file the name of the role". If only the name of the role is provided we cannot access the role via `.get()`. I agree using an ID to access a role is better than using the name, However the usage of an ID is not brought up. My first code sample is my definitive answer, while the second being an example of a fail safe given that the name was misspelled while also assuming most *will* name their muted role along the lines of "muted". The choice of `.get()` vs `.find()` is up to the OP.